# Java Getting JTable Value (Per row)

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I would like to get the value from the Jtable, and I tried it using the getvalueat however whenever I try to get the value from the JTable it only get the value from the first column of the selected row, I need to get all the value from the Jtable which I selected. Can you please help me with this one

```
here is my code:
class GetTableValue implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        AbstractButton button = (AbstractButton)e.getSource();
        if(e.getActionCommand().equals(button.getActionCommand)){
            int row = table.getSelectedRow();
            int col = table.getSelectedColumn();

            Object data = (Object)table.getValueAt(row, col);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, data);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my action event where the value of the selected table is shown in the JOptionPane unfortunately it only display one value(which is the one you already selected) not the whole row.

This code is for my Jbutton for call the action event(I already excluded my code from the JTable since it fetch the Jtable value from my database)

```
ActionListener tableAction = new GetTableValue();


buttonEdit = new JButton("EDIT");


buttonEdit.addActionListener(tableAction);
```

the code is plain and simple, I also search Mr. G(google) about a good tutorial on fetching row, unfortunately there isn't a good tutorial for fetching Jtable value(per row).

Comment: I suggest you to use JXTable from SwingX framework.

Comment: Please add the Swing tag to posts using Swing components!  I hoped the last couple of times I did it for you, *might* have given you the hint.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`getValueAt` will return you the value of the cell (at row/col). Unless you're table model supports it, there is no convenient way (beyond what you are doing) to get the whole row in a single request.

Also, remember, if the table is sorted or filtered, the model indices will not match the view, you need to convert them first, using [`convertRowIndexToModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertRowIndexToModel(int)) and [`convertColumnIndexToModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertColumnIndexToModel(int))

**UPDATE**

The only way around it is if the table model you're using has a `getRow` (or equivalent) method.  Without know how you are storing the data in the table model it's next to near impossible to give an accurate answer, but a general idea would be...

```
public class MyAwesomeTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    // All the usual stuff...

    public MyRowData getRowAt(int index) { ... }
}
```

Now, `MyRowData` is what ever implementation of the table data you've created.  It could be (preferably) a single `Object` or in the case of the `DefaultTableModel` an array of objects.

```
class GetTableValue implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        AbstractButton button = (AbstractButton)e.getSource();
        if(e.getActionCommand().equals(button.getActionCommand)){

            int row = table.convertRowIndexToModel(table.getSelectedRow());
            MyAwesomeTableModel model = (MyAwesomeTableModel)table.getModel();

            MyRowData data = model.getRowAt(row);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, data);
        }
    }
}
```

This is all dependent on how you've implemented your `TableModel` and how you've implemented your row data, but that's the general jist

Comment: Is there any other way?  should I say "Cheat" to make this thing work I open and read the links that you gave to me and it's a bit complicated for me to understand :)

Comment: Can you please advise me, is it better to just get the id in the Jtable and search it in the database then store the fetch value in an array or variable?

Comment: I can't say it will help you immediately, but that's the general jist

Comment: Thanks I'll study this first. If this is the best way to get my desired output :)

Comment: It's the best way I know (that doesn't mean much but hay ;))

Comment: To write a own getRowAt(int) method of your own TableModel can be a little bit tricky. Because if the user can change the sort order of your table (by clicking on a table header), the getRowAt(int) method must be get the right object ....

Comment: @Steffen No it doesn't, the model remains unaffected when sorted and the `JTable` does a translation between itself and the model automatically...

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Both are not really right. If you use JTable.getSelectedRow() you are right: The index returned will be the correct (unsorted) index of the TableModel. But the method JTable.prepareRenderer(...) will use the sorted index as row number. But I have now also found out that there are two methods RowSorter.convertRowIndexTo...(int) for converting the sorted and unsorted indexes (you can get the RowSorter by calling JTable.getRowSorter()).

Comment: @Steffen You should be look at `JTable#convertRowIndexToModel` and `JTable#convertRowIndexToView`.  If, for example, you used `getSelectedRow` and then used `JTable#getValue`, you would not have to do any conversion, as the the table will do the conversion for you (from view to model), if you attempted to used the selected index, you would need to first use `JTable#convertRowIndexToModel` before request the value directly from the model, as has been demonstrated.  General rule of thumb, when taking a index from the view/model to the mode/view, you must convert it.

Comment: @Steffen *"If you use JTable.getSelectedRow() you are right"* - No, it's not, it's the "views" or the "sorted" index.  `JTable.prepareRenderer(...)` relies on `JTable#getValueAt`, which uses `JTable#convertRowIndexToView` to convert the view index to the model index, which is all demonstrated in the answer.  `JTable` works with the sorted indices to maintain the consistency with the view, when it communicates with the model, it converts that index into the model context, as you should do to...

Answer (score 12):

If you want all the values from selected row then try this [code](http://www.tutorialdata.com/examples/java/swing/jtable).

```
int row = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
int column = jTable1.getColumnCount();
for(int i = 0; i < column; i++) {
    System.out.println(jTable1.getValueAt(row, i));
}
```

You get the all values for selected row, no matter how much columns are there in [jtable](http://www.tutorialdata.com/examples/java/swing/jtable)

If you want all the values from jtable then try:

```
int row = jTable1.getRowCount();
int column = jTable1.getColumnCount();
for (int j = 0; j  < row; j++) {
    for (int i = 0; i  < column; i++) {
        System.out.println(jTable1.getValueAt(j, i));
    }
}
```

Yes you can use `Object[]` to store the values. For example:

```
Object[] val = new Object[column];
for (int k = 0; k  < val.length - 1; k++) {
    for (int j = 0; j  < row; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i  < column; i++) {
            val[k] = jTable1.getValueAt(j, i);
            System.out.println(val[k]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow it worked! thanks, it fetch the Jtable value and printed it.

Comment: However how can I store the value to a variable? should I use the Object[] array to store it?

Comment: Yes you can use Object[] see the example in my answer. I hope its work for you.

Comment: There is a problem in the last example, it should be `Object[][] val = new Object[row][column]`. Then remove the top-most `for(int k...)` and do `val[j][i] = jTable1.getValueAt(j,i)`.

Otherwise you will overwrite `val[k]` at each row.

Answer (score 2):

```
private void jTable1MousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     

int selectedRow;

ListSelectionModel rowSM = jTable1.getSelectionModel();

  rowSM.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener()
  {
    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) 
    {
        ListSelectionModel lsm = (ListSelectionModel) e.getSource();

        selectedRow = lsm.getMinSelectionIndex();

        int numCols = jTable1.getColumnCount();

        model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();

        System.out.print(" \n row " + selectedRow + ":");

        for (int j = 0; j < numCols; j++) 
        {
            System.out.print(" " + model.getValueAt(selectedRow, j));
        }

    }
});
}
```

Using this you can get value of whole row where u click on particular row.

Comment: So every time the use clicks the table, you add another selection listener? That's going to get messy really quickly

Answer (score 1):

you can try the below code to get selected row value:

```
int selectedRow = jTableName.getSelectedRow();
selectedRow = jTableName.convertRowIndexToModel(selectedRow);
String val1 = (String)jTableName.getModel().getValueAt(selectedRow, 0);
String val2 = (String)jTableName.getModel().getValueAt(selectedRow, 1);
```