# Get index of dynamic checkbox in java

Tags: java, dynamic, netbeans, checkbox

I have dynamic checkbox in jtable , I do it by this code

```
 TableColumn tcolumnas = jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(3);
 tcolumnas.setCellRenderer(jTable1.getDefaultRenderer(Boolean.class));
 tcolumnas.setCellEditor(jTable1.getDefaultEditor(Boolean.class));
```

and I want if I check one of them I want to know the index of check box.

Hearing for your suggestion

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tskSw.png

UPDATE :

the solution is veeery simple as here
[Java Getting JTable Value (Per row)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12275011/java-getting-jtable-value-per-row)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `TableModelListener` to the `TableModel`. An event will be fired any time the data in a cell is changed.

Comment: thank you for replay , could you please more explain the idea ? this how I build the 'TableModel' 
`DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel();
dtm.addColumn("TagDesc");
dtm.addColumn("Sol.Verifying");`

Comment: A TableModelListener is like any other listener. An event is fired when something happens. Read the TableModelListener API and implement the method defined in the interface. If you are not sure how to do this, you can search for the forum or the web for examples that use a TableModelListener